# Probleme controlling financial dimensions in purchase requisition line detail

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am trying to have some control over the financial dimension fields in the purchase requisition line detail, I need to auto get the CostCenter value depending on the Fixed Asset selected, I have the relation stored on the fixed asset value models but my problem is that I couldn't access those financial dimension fields. Apparently they are generated by code using some class which I couldn't figure out how to use

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to get the CostCenter various ways in this post: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/210419?pi61711=2#responses

ievvgen's answers are probably the most reliable.